# Updating a page element in a php script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Page elements are defined like this.

```
<div id="readf" class="tabbertab">
<h2>First Reading</h2>

    <div id='titlefe' class='rtitle'>

    </div>
    <div id='readfe' class='rtext'>

    </div>

</div>
```

I make an ajax call to a php script to add data to these page elements.

```
<script>
    $('#readings').ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "loadenglish.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: { },
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != '') 
            {
                alert (response);
            }
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert ("status "+status+" error "+error+"responseText "+request.responseText);
        },
    });    

    });
</script>
```

The php script gets the data and does a script echo to add the data.

```
<?php
    $titlefe = 'text 1';

    $readfe = 'text 2';

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> $('#titlefe').append('".$titlefe."');  $('#readfe').append('".$readfe."'); </script>";
?>
```

The alert statements shows that the php script gets the right information.  But the page elements are not updated.  Is there a different way to add `$titlefe` to element id `titlefe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what MK_Dev posted you can use PHP function json_encode();

```
<?php

//loadenglish.php
$params = array(
    'titlefe' => 'text 1',
    'readfe' => 'text 2',
);

echo json_encode($params);
```

Also there is a jQuery function [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), which is a shortcut for $.ajax() function usage like yours.

Comment: This works if I update the ajax call to include `datatype: 'json'`.  Then I can retrieve the info with `response.titlefe` and `response.readfe` for the page elements.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `eval(response);` after your alert in the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

Returning javascript methods is not a good idea. You should return data in JSON format and use javascript on the client side to perform the actual update.

Your PHP return statement should look like:

```
echo "{ 'titlefe': '" + $titlefe + "', 'readfe': '" + $readfe + "' }";
```

and your success call back should look like this:

```
success: function(response) {
   $('#titlefe').text(response.titlefe);
   $('#readfe').text(response.readfe);
}
```

Comment: There are situations where you need to return javascript.  I.E., jsonp, iframe form submissions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on returning JavaScript, you should be using [`getScript()`](http://jQuery.getScript/) instead of an Ajax get.